# Removing whitespace in jQuery

Tags: javascript, regex

Right now my code is able to remove additional spaces, but it seems to mess up with new lines. If there are multiple breaks in the input, it removes all lines breaks. For example:

**Input:**

```
abc    xyz

test
```

**Output:**

```
abc xzy test
```

Ideally, I'd like the output to be:

```
abc xyz

test
```

Code:

```
var input   = $('textarea#input');
var output  = $('textarea#output');

input.bind('keyup', function() {
    output.val(input.val().replace(/(\s){2,}/g, ' '));
});
```

**jsFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/rdvR7/3/

I would also like to keep tabs, but haven't figured out how to use `\t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use character classs to replace only spaces.

```
 output.val(input.val().replace(/[ ]{2,}/g,' '));
```

This would only find spaces, not tab characters and newlines.  You could also put any combination of characters inside the brackets

```
 output.val(input.val().replace(/[ \t]{2,}/g,' '));
```

This would find all spaces and all tab characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the space character (which represents itself in regex):

```
output.val(input.val().replace(/ {2,}/g, ' '));
```