# Removing multiple characters (\n and " ") from textarea

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove multiple spaces and \n characters from my textarea using jquery.
For example,

```
"this is    a

dog"
```

should be `"this is a dog"`

Please help me out!

Comment: please provide some code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing whitespace in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595021/removing-whitespace-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript regex

```
$('#myTextArea').val($('#myTextArea').val().replace(/ +(?= )/g, '').replace(/\n+/g, ''));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/241/

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your textarea name is `textarea`
then use

```
$('#textarea').val().replace(/ /g, '').replace(/\n/g, '');
```

This should work out.